If a root of the equation $az^2+bz+c = 0$ has modulus 1, then $b^2=ac$.
I need help with this problem. Any hint or recommendation to do it differently.
Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be different complex numbers ($\neq 0$) such that $\left | a \right |=\left | b \right |=\left | c \right |$. If a root of the equation $az^2+bz+c$ = 0 has modulus 1, then $b^2=ac$. (The problem is written like this)
My attempt:
Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be the roots of the polynomial. Using Vieta's formulas I know that
$$b=-a(z_1+z_2)\;\; , \;\;c=az_1z_2$$
So by hypothesis I will have
$$\left | a \right |=\left | b \right |=\left | c \right |\;\Leftrightarrow \; \left |a  \right |=\left |-a(z_1+z_2)  \right |=\left |az_1z_2  \right | $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \; 1=\left |z_1+z_2  \right |=\left |z_1z_2  \right | $$
and assuming that $\left |z_1  \right |=1$
$$1=\left |z_1+z_2  \right |=\left |z_2  \right |$$
However, I do not see how, from these equalities, I can reach the result that is requested of me. I already tried to manipulate the expression $b^2$ to get to the right side without any result.

Notice that squaring the sum formula gives us the relation (after substituting using the product formula) $a^2(z_1^2 + z_2^2) + 2ac = b^2$. So for the conclusion to hold, it is sufficient to show that $a^2(z_1^2 + z_2^2) = -ac$.

Let $z$ denote the root of the equation and $|z|=1.$ We have $$ab^{-1}z+1+cb^{-1}z^{-1}=0$$ Hence the imaginary parts of the numbers $ab^{-1}z$ and $cb^{-1}z^{-1}$ are opposite. As both numbers have absolute value equal $1, $ their product is equal $1.$ Thus we obtain $acb^{-2}=1.$
Remark The converse implication holds. Indeed, if $b^2=ac,$ then multiplying the equation by $z-ba^{-1}$ gives  $$a(z^3-b^3a^{-3})=0$$ All three solutions of that equation have absolute value equal $1.$

Okay, @Ryszard, I've seen you frequently produce very elegant solutions to a variety of problems, but this one has me scratching my head - I'd love to know where you got the idea to approach it this way.

@JonathanZ Thanks. It is hard to explain, but my first idea was   that $1$ is the root of $$\tilde{a}z^2+\tilde{b}z+c=0$$ where $\tilde{a}=az_1^2$ and $\tilde{b}=bz_1.$ The OP claim for this equation is $(bz_1)^2=az_1^2c,$ which is equivalent to the OP claim for the original equation. We have $\tilde{a}+\tilde{b}+c=0.$ Then it is tempting to divide by one of the numbers to make use of the complex conjugate method. There are three possible choices, one of them leads to the conclusion. The other two are $\tilde{a}^2=\tilde{b}c$ and $c^2=\tilde{a}\tilde{b}.$

Thanks, it's a very impressive solution :)

@Ryszard (+1) to your above explanation.

${\bf Solution \, 1.}$ Dividing through by $a$, you can assume $a = 1$ and $|b| = |c| = 1$; this does affect whether or not $b^2 = ac$. Writing $c = e^{i\alpha}$, you can also replace $z$ by $ze^{i{\alpha \over 2}}$ and assume that $a = 1$; this replacement too will not affect whether or not $b^2 = ac$. So we have reduced to the case where $|b| = 1$ and the following equation has a root of magnitude $1$:
$$z^2 + bz + 1 = 0$$
If $e^{i\beta}$ is a root of magnitude $1$, then since the constant term is $1$ the other root must be $e^{-i\beta}$. Then $b = -2\cos\beta$ is real. Since $|b| = 1$, one must have $b = 1$ or $-1$. In either case $b^2 = ac$ as desired.
${\bf Solution \, 2.}$ Consider $az^2$, $bz$ and $c$ as two-dimensional vectors ${\bf u}, {\bf v},$ and ${\bf w}$ respectively. Then ${\bf u}, {\bf v},$ and ${\bf w}$ are vectors of the same length that sum to zero. Hence they are the sides of an equilateral triangle. Thus either ${\bf v} = {\bf u}e^{2\pi i \over 3}$ and ${\bf w} = {\bf u}e^{4\pi i \over 3}$, or ${\bf v} = {\bf u}e^{-{2\pi i \over 3}}$ and ${\bf w} = {\bf u}e^{-{4\pi i \over 3}}$. In either case, $(az^2)c = (bz)^2$, which reduces to the desired conclusion that $ac = b^2$.

Thanks for your comment : )
